# data arguments are not working as expected in Hive

Tags: hive

I am passing data parameters to hive script, but it's not working.

```
SET yrmonth=concat(substr(to_date(${hiveconf:runningdate}),1,4),substr(to_date(${hiveconf:runningdate}),6,2));
SET fom=TRUNC(${hiveconf:runningdate},'MONTH');
SET lom=LAST_DAY(${hiveconf:runningdate});

USE cust_db;

SELECT saleid,podid,pname
    FROM product 
    WHERE productln_yrmo=${hiveconf:yrmonth};
```

--productln_yrmo is int column

```
SELECT cid,cname,cloc
    FROM customer 
    WHERE customer_createddt >='${hiveconf:fom}' 
    AND customer_createddt <='${hiveconf:lom}'
    AND cloc = 'AUS';
```

--customer_createddt is date column

```
hive -hiveconf runningdate='2016-05-18' -f cust.hql
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for the community to be able to help you, you need to first specify your exact issue and the specific question you have regarding it.

Comment: Could you please help me ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

from your query,  'customer_createddt' seems to be DATE type since you have used with '<=' and '>=' operators to get the range of values between 'fom' and 'lom'.  I guess lexicographic comparison  for date range works fine perfectly . But, not sure when  table DDL created with a partition on 'customer_createddt' column.
So please give a try  casting  string to date ( also please post your table DDL for more clarity)

```
SELECT cid,cname,cloc
    FROM customer 
    WHERE customer_createddt >=CAST(${hiveconf:fom} AS DATE) 
    AND customer_createddt <=CAST(${hiveconf:lom} AS DATE)
    AND cloc = 'AUS';
```